# Google map navigator.geolocation failing in safari 7.0.1

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, safari

I have a problem with google map navigator service. I have to zoom in on the part of the  map where the user is located. So I have decided to use the navigator service provided by google.

This works fine for all the browser except safari 7.0.1. I have used the code given on this [demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation?hl=pt-br) as a reference.

Below is a screen shot of the demo example as seen on Safari 7.0.1.

EDIT:

1: Didn't work even after allowing the browser to use my location.

2: Works fine on safari 6.1.1 and not 7.0.1.

[image]

Any work around for this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: navigator.geolocation is not _google_ code it is a browser facility.  Sounds like it doesn't exist in Safari 7.0.1 (or perhaps you denied sharing your position as indicated in the `// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.`)

Comment: Did Safari ask you if it was ok to access the location? Perhaps this is disabled in your browser security or you have previously denied it for this website?

If Safari had no access, then this error would  make sense.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention it. I had allowed the browser to access the data regarding my location. And yet it did not work

Comment: @shrujanshetty You could try the nightly version of Safari (Webkit): http://nightly.webkit.org/

If it works here, then it may in fact be a bug with Safari 7.0.1

Comment: @BlakeSimpson I have tried running the code on safari 6.1.1. And it works fine but does not run on safari 7.0.1